# How should i treat multi-valued logic in a canonical overlap calculation?

Tags: database, overlap, canonical-link, data-management

The Situation:

```
B->TCW
C->WG
TCB->OMW
L->UNM
TL->CGM
```

Now i have to calculate the canonical overlap and remove the redundancies.

After left and right reduction i get the following result

```
B -> TC
C -> WG
TCB -> OM
L -> UNM
TL -> C
```

So the question is, what would happen if i had two more functional dependences?

e.g.

```
B->TCW
C->WG
TCB->OMW
L->UNM
TL->CGM

BL ->-> F
BL ->-> G
```

From my point of view or understanding, i would say both new multi-valued logics does not has any influence to the canonical overlap. So the result would be the same just with the two multi-valued logics.

But what would happen if we had a multi-valued logic which has influence to the result?

Is it permitted to cross out the duplicates or is it not allowed, because if we have a multi-valued logic every letter will be a key value?